# iOS 8: get resource from Cocoa Touch Framework

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios8

To share code and resources between my app and extensions, I embed a `Cocoa Touch Framework` in my project, this framework contains some resources like image and xib files.

My question is: how do I access those resources from may main app and extensions?

I used to use this method: [iOS 8 Extension: how to use xib inside Cocoa Touch Framework in extensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25397238/ios-8-extension-how-to-use-xib-inside-cocoa-touch-framework-in-extensions)

but this will **make a copy to all resources in app's bundle and extensions' bundle**, which is not a good repeat.

Is there a better way?

**Update:**

Now my main app can use code like this to access resource in frameworks:

```
+(NSBundle*)frameworkBundle
{
    NSString *frameworkDirPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] privateFrameworksPath];
    NSString *frameworkBundlePath = [frameworkDirPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyFramework.framework"];
    NSBundle *frameworkBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:frameworkBundlePath];

    return frameworkBundle;
}
```

but this doesn't work for extensions.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this:

```
NSBundle *frameworkBundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[AnyClassFromFramework class]];
```

Comment: It throws a different route than the code that is in the question, why?  what should we use?

Comment: Creating bundle using bundleForClass is better than creating from path.
I faced this issue during development, wherein we were consuming coredata momd file from test app, after that we converted the app into a framework and added momd as a resource.

Now the test app which was consuming the momd file was looking for it in mainBundle, whereas it's incorrect now. momd file is moved inside framework. So always use bundleForClass and provide the class which is closest/directly using the resource.

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me:

```
NSBundle * frameworkBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithIdentifier:@"<framework-bundle-identifier>"];
```

Comment: This works for dynamic library only, for static library it returns nil.

Answer (score 0):

For **swift**, consider using:

```
let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType)
```

Comment: This is for Swift 3+ only.